# Runtime method argument type information in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I want to fetch information about the types of the arguments in an instance-method at runtime.

For instance if I have the method:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithItem:(Item *)item usingName:(id<Type2>)name;
```

Here I would like to retrieve `Item` and `id<Type2>`.

Is there any way of doing this, or is there no type information available for the arguments at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is "runtime" method argument type information, which is basically the [NSMethodSignature class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMethodSignature_Class/Reference/Reference.html) all about. However, all Objective-C types i.e. `Item*` and `id<Type2>` will be conflated to `id` when compiling, i.e. you can't distinguish between different `id` subtypes.

Comment: ... as well you can't distinguish between certain other types, either.  The @encode goop in Objective-C is woefully broken.